# CPPUnit array assert

Tags: c++, cppunit

I'm kinda new to C++ and even more CPPUnit. Can somebody tell me what should I use to assert for array values (compare them to expected). Should I use memcmp or is there something better in CPPUnit, C++ in general or any other library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In modern C++, we compare ranges of data for equality with [std::equal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal).